# Why does a pendulum move backward in an accelerated car?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

When a pendulum is attached to the ceiling of an accelerated car it goes backward and performs oscillation why is it so? Is it because of inertia or because of the pseudo force? When will it be stationary and make a certain angle with the vertical?

Answer (score 1):

Both: in the reference frame of the car (which is not inertial because it is accelerated), one sees a pseudo-force, while in a frame being at rest it is just the inertia of the pendulum. As long as the force is constantly applied/the car is constantly accelerating, the pendulum should find a stationary position (assuming there is friction). You can find that angle by adding the force accelerating the car and the gravitational force going downward.

Comment: at the force balance position it would already have velocity... and it will further go ahead thus how will it find stationary position?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The stationary position has nothing to do with velocity, only with acceleration/forces. If the pendulum has no friction it will keep oscillating around the stationary point, but if there is friction it will loose energy until it reaches the stationary position.

Comment: Ok got it thankss

Comment: @Paul Why are you saying there must  be friction in order for the pendulum to find a stationary position when the acceleration of the car is constant?

Comment: As long as it didn't start in that position, yes: an undampened oscillator wont stop oscillating once it is set into motion by the car starting to accelerate.

Answer (score 0):

if you start to accelerate inertia  will get (better keep)  your pendulum backward, since your acceleration will not be steady for very long it starts to oscillate. If you could keep your acceleration constant it would just  stay in its backward position 
 since the two accelerations g downward , and a horizontal would ad.

Answer (score 0):

When a pendulum mass is at it's equilibrium position in an inertial frame, the sum of forces (weight and cable tension) $\Sigma F = 0$.

When it is accelerating in a car, that sum is no more zero, but $\Sigma \mathbf F = m\mathbf a$.

As $\mathbf a$ is a vector pointing forwards, $\Sigma \mathbf F$ also must point forwards.

As the source of the force over the mass is the cable, it must be inclined backwards, so that a component of its tension be horizontal, pointing forwards.

If it is displaced backward from the equilibrium position, the horizontal force increase, increasing its acceleration. The opposite if it is displaced forward. For an external inertial frame, the pendulum oscilates, alternating positions more acelerated and less accelerated than the car.

Comment: "For an external inertial frame, the pendulum oscilates" Until friction stops it from doing so, and it comes to rest at the angle dictated by the combination of gravity and the accelerating force.